# Django APNS and Phonegap suggestions

Tags: ios, django, cordova, apple-push-notifications

I was wondering if I could get some recommendations for what people have used for background Push Notifications in iOS with Django and/or PhoneGap. Looking forward to hear your comments!

Thanks,
Steve

---

This is what I've found so far:
https://github.com/stephenmuss/django-ios-notifications
Seems pretty comprehensive, but seeing as I haven't done any work with APNS, not sure if it's enough. Also, last update was done about a year ago.

https://github.com/appsome/django-ios-push
Seems like a very simple implementation based on another older project.

PyAPNS
https://github.com/samuraisam/pyapns
Seems to have a bunch of tutorials written about it. Updates haven't been made recently.

---

On the PhoneGap side, this one looks like the winner: 
https://github.com/mgcrea/cordova-push-notification
From this tutorial:

http://devgirl.org/2012/10/19/tutorial-apple-push-notifications-with-phonegap-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

[PushPlugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin) works on both iOS and Android. It's among the supported plugins for [PhoneGap Build](https://build.phonegap.com).

On backend side we've been using python library apns-client. See [this list for alternatives](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=apns&submit=search).

Comment: Thanks @lekksi. PushPlugin looks interesting and well supported. I started with Stephen Muss's plugin.